# How to add a scale or a ruler in Palantir Foundry Map?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-slate

I would like to know how to add a scale to the Foundry Slate Map.

Is there an attribute to enable as in Google Maps?
*scaleControl: true*

Or how to add a ruler as in Google Maps?

There are several attributes that can be used to calculate the distance between two points in Maps widget.

- zoomLevel
- bounds.northEast.latitude
- bounds.northEast.longitude
- bounds.southWest.latitude
- bounds.southWest.longitude

Using these attributes, I tried to add a ruler with a fixed length but with a distance value updating accordingly. But it is not successful.

Thanks,
Madhubhani

Answer (score 0):

There is a dedicated map application which has a scale. Maybe that would help you in this particular instance ?

Comment: You mean [Ontology Map](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/map/overview/)? It's not possible for me to change the application now.
I already have an application built using [Slate](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/slate/overview/) and I just want to add a scale to it's [map](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/slate/widgets-visualization/#map).